# force image reload html5

Tags: html

Is there a clean way to tell browser not to cache image in img tag like

```
<img src="" cahe="no-cache"/>
```

or force reload it with html5? If not, maybe you know where can i suggest it, because the problem is around for quite a while...

I know you can attach "?randomstring" at the end of src parameter or use server scripting to read file and send it with headers, which is what i am doing now, so i'm not looking for a hack.

"no-cache", "expire" and other headers for whole document doesn't seem to work on image files or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Instead remove unwanted attributes using $(img).removeAttr("attribute-name"), cache is server sided whereas img is client script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the caching headers for the **image** not the document.

HTML 5 adds nothing to control the caching of external resources.

Comment: Can you provide an example if we're talking about html? I know how to do it server side. Just wondering can we do it on client.

Comment: You can't set HTTP response headers on the client. You have to do it server side.

Comment: So you could just have answered - there is no way to do that with html :)

Comment: That was implied in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set those headers for the images, check your web server's documentation to see how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

For each image, browser sends a separate request, web servers usually serve static files (including images, CSS stylesheets, JavaScript script files, etc.) directly without giving them to a kind of handler. Thus, you should consult your web server to set **Cach-Contro** headers as you said. 
Another way is to write an extension for your web server (ASP.NET has an integrated pipeline with IIS7 for example) to server static files yourself. That is the only way you can force cache-servers and clients not to cache your image and get it every time from server.